# How can I rename files uploaded through ADAM in 2SXC?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Using the 2SXC Content module, I have a simple Hero content type and template that includes a title and a background image. I use a C# Razor template and when my users upload a background image via ADAM, the razor template applies the background through inline CSS. Something like this:

```
@if (Content.BackgroundImage != "") {
   <style type="text/css">
    section.hero {
     background-image: url(@Content.BackgroundImage);
   }
}
```

The problem is that if the user uploads a file name that has spaces and/or illegal characters, the background image will not appear because the browser doesn't like spaces in the filenames in the inline CSS.

How can I make it so that the file uploaded by ADAM strips out the spaces and removes the illegal characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Content.BackgroundImage).Replace("+", "%20").Replace("%2f","/")
```

Using iJungleBoy's suggestion, I used HttpUtility.URLEncode. But it replaced the spaces with +, and / with %2f, so I use .Replace to swap out + for %20 and %f for / to make a nice simple URL. This now accepts images with spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to url-encode them, like replacing  with `%20`. Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525738(v%3Dvs.90) or  `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or one of the variations :)

Comment: This resource helps. Using this, I ended up making some more code to fit my example.